# Multithreading for faster image download in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, web-crawler

I have a list of 4 million car data and their image urls. 
The data is stored in following manner in database:

```
image_paths: ["1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_0.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_1.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_2.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_3.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_4.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_5.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_6.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_7.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_8.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_9.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_10.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_11.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_12.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_13.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_14.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_15.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_16.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_17.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_18.jpeg", "1FMCU0GD8HUA54186_19.jpeg"]}
 image_urls: ['https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-2184995423804160536-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-4540782425872667330-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-7243950089579631983-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-7710811720569469291-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-4031294549357151940-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-2789177086013778346-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-2720528876996226217-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-569475168753946872-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-72573478566280418-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-16994607167444151-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-8688248577169769701-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-2906095547280134476-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-4407739760966857172-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-3736759056303011298-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-4880108030264007082-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-267003030201578621-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-7577378734962701801-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-2130803651949430876-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-8952104950656887251-1024x768.jpeg', 'https://static.cargurus.com/images/forsale/2018/12/27/23/15/2017_ford_escape-pic-6495738051060732844-1024x768.jpeg']
```

I have these two columns for each of the 4 million cars. Now I want to download the images as fast as possible and as far as my research I came to know that multithreading is the best way to do this,of which I don't have any idea. Can any one please help me out with the code? I want it to be in python. 
For downloading the images I have already written the function.

```
def downloadImageFunc(self,fileName,url):
    # print url
    resp1=urllib.urlopen(url)
    self.uploadUrl(resp1,fileName)
```

Comment: While you can do threading in Python, due to the global interpreter lock (GIL) only one thread can execute a a time. So I would suggest either to use sub processing instead or maybe take a look at https://github.com/requests/requests-threads.

Remember to keep track of how many subprocesses you start to avoid bringing your system down

Comment: GIL is not a problem when it comes to IO operations. Multithreading is just fine for fetching data. I suggest to take a look at multiprocessing.dummy module (name is a bit confusing - it's multithreading module) - especially at Pool class and its "map" method.